# How we use Loadrunner parameterization technique for distribute the parameterize data to different virtual devices while run time?

Tags: .net, sybase, load-testing, performance-testing, loadrunner

I am using LoadRunner for test mobile application which is developed in Sybase Unwired Platform technology.

I recorded the LoadRunner script and I can able to run in LoadRunnear but for Load Testing we have to create more virtual devices that time we have to pass the different values to different Virtual devices for this scenario I used parametrization but its not working in my scenario could any one help me for resolve this issue.

P.S. parametrization works fine for iteration of the execute the script but my scenarios is one time I have to run the script with (ex) 100 users.

Thanks in advance,
Karthick

Answer (score 0):

This precise scenario is covered both in the HP produced training material as well as the online book in the chapter on parameterization.  If you are being asked to deliver without having been though training then your manager is setting you up to fail.     This is not a reflection on your skills, but on your managers behavior

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are asking about could be resolved by changing the value in the 'Parameter List' window from 'Select next row : Sequential' to 'Unique'.

This will force the individual virtual users to use unique data subsets of your parameters, as in no two users will use the same data rows. You can then allocate the number of rows of parameters to push to each virtual user and their behavior once they run out of their allocated data sets.